# strange c++ behaviour for shift operator

Tags: c++

I was tinkering with a C++ program and I stumbled upon a really strange thing.

This code outputs 0:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout<<(1<<(32LL));
}
```

while this one outputs 1:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    long long int a=32;
    cout<<(1<<a);
}
```

Why is this?